# PHP function to return the length of the longest string argument

Tags: php

Eg:

`GetLogestString("bae","afaaa","aaa")` should return 5

`GetLogestString("baeedfefe","afaaaa","aaa","bb")` should return 9

Comment: I fail at seeing the question in this post.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), [`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php), [`max()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) and [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php):

```
function getLongestString() {
  $args = func_get_args();
  return max(array_map('strlen', $args));
}
```

**Edit:** In PHP 5.2 you have to store the result of `func_get_args()` in a temporary variable. In PHP 5.3 you can do this:

```
function getLongestString() {
  return max(array_map('strlen', func_get_args()));
}
```

Comment: Only detail (which may or may not be wanted) is that if you call getLongestString("aaaaa","aa",99999999) it'll return 8, not 5.

Comment: Fatal error: func_get_args(): Can't be used as a function parameter

Comment: Srinivas Tamada: use a more recent PHP version. 5.3 has been out for quite a while now and has many improvements.

Comment: @Srinivas Tamada: Workaround: Store `func_get_args()` in a temporary variable and use this for the `array_map`.