# Finding how many digits does every number has in an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which has several numbers.
What I want to do is get a loop and run into this array and count how many two-digits numbers, three-digits, four-digits numbers do I have.

What I have tried:

```
$myArray = array(123,1234,12345,123456,123567);
for($i=1,$size=count($myArray);$i<=$size;i++)
{
if(strlen($i==3)) echo "the number with index " .$i. " is three-digit number.";
else if(strlen($i==4)) echo "the number with index " .$i. " is four-digit number.";
...
}
```

I also tried this:

```
$threeDigits=0;
$fourDigits=0;
$fiveDigits=0;
$sixDigits=0;

$myArray=(123,1234,12345,123456,1234567,111,222)
for($i=1,$size=count($myArray);$i<=$size;i++)
{
if(strlen($==3)) $threeDigits++;
else if(strlen($i==4)) $fourDigits++;
else if(strlen($i==5)) $fiveDigits++;
else if(strlen($i==6)) $sixDigits++;
}
echo "There are " .$fourDigits. " numbers with 4 digits.";
echo "There are " .$threeDigits. " numbers with 3 digits.";
echo "There are " .$fiveDigits. " numbers with 5 digits.";
echo "There are " .$sixDigits. " numbers with 6 digits.";
```

But somehow it only reads them as one. As you can see, in my array there are three three-digit numbers but when I print it out it says I have only one. What do you think it might be the problem here?

Comment: I'm not sure of the metrics involved but perhaps sort the array first?

Comment: What does sorting helps here with?

Comment: Define "best"...what are you unhappy about in the current solution? It's hard to suggest an improvement unless you can describe a problem and/or a more specific goal

Comment: Hint: iterating over array is simplier with `foreach` -> `foreach(myArray as key, value) ` or just `foreach(myArray as value)`

Comment: Near dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1762216/2943403; I'll try to find a better one

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50145408/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/4598048/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/2309626/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/32430993/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/59785175/2943403

Comment: Can you please take a look at my edited question?

Answer (score 0):

Just for the hell of it, map it as a callback:

```
foreach(array_map('strlen', $myArray) as $key => $len) {
    echo "the number with index $key is a $len digit number.";
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please take a look at my edited question? Maybe it will give you a clearer idea of what I want to achieve. I don't want the index of the two/three/four digit number, I  want to count how many three/four/five-digit numbers I have.

Answer (score -1):

Store the lengths in an array:

```
$myArray = array(123,1234,12345,123456,123567);
$lengths = [];
foreach ( $myArray as $val ) {
  $lengths[strlen($val)]++;
}

foreach (range(2,4) as $len)  {
  echo "There are " . $lengths[$len] . " $len-digit numbers\n";
}
```